# How to convert a 2D texture DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM to DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM without device to host transfer?

Tags: opencl, directx-11, desktop-duplication

I have a project, which captures screenshots using a Microsoft Desktop Duplication Api and processes them using a set of OpenCL kernels in realtime.
Screenshot itself never gets transfered to the host(CPU). It is a console application.

I've ran into some portability issues with Nvidia OpenCL runtime.
Microsoft Desktop Duplication Api result/screenshot uses DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM format and Nvidia implementation doesn't support it.
Only DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM is supported.